# capture gsap animations as does the "animation" tool in chrome

Tags: gsap

As the animation tab in chrome capture the standard css animation, :
[image: anilmation tab in chrome]

is there a way to capture gsap animation and timeline ? As it modified directly the style property of each element, It doesn't appear as an animation. It might not be the exact explanation, but it doesn't appear as an animation in chrome in any case.
Thanks for your help.